# Google Sheets Candlestick Chart modify high and low line width?

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, google-visualization, candlestick-chart

I have been working with Google's Candlestick charts and customized everything to my needs, except that the width of the lines above and below the candlestick cannot be modified, or simply I have not found a way to do so. My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<script>
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
        ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
        ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
        ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
        ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
        // Treat first row as data as well.
        ], true);

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, {
        selectionMode: 'multiple',
        backgroundColor: {
            strokeWidth: 3,
            stroke: 'black',
        },
        vAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                count: -1,
            },
            minorGridlines: {
                count: 4,
            }
        },
        hAxis: {
            textStyle: {
                color: 'white',
            }
        },
        focusTarget: 'category',
        colors: ['black', 'black'],
        legend: 'none',
        theme: 'maximized',
        candlestick: {
            hollowIsRising: 'false',
            risingColor: {
                fill: 'green',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 1, // Here you can clearly see that I changed the candlestick's stroke to a smaller value which would basically be the same as decreasing the "border width".
            },
            fallingColor: {
                fill: 'red',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 1, // Here you can clearly see that I changed the candlestick's stroke to a smaller value which would basically be the same as decreasing the "border width".
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

This works perfectly fine, however, the lines that appear above and below are perhaps "bigger" or in terms of styling "fat" which does not combine with the candlestick's *strokeWidth*. The styling appears ugly and the transition does not quite fit. Is there a way to set these line to the same size as the candlestick's *strokeWidth*? I've tried the following code:

```
    bar: {
        strokeWidth: 1,
    },
```

Sadly, it does not work. Hope you guys have got some ideas. King Regards!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with those charts, what would the lines above and below be called? [Candlesticks API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart#Configuration_Options) just in case you want to have a look.

Comment: Hi @hoshhunt I've already read through the Candlesticks API like 10 times and don't find anything. I've researched other sites as well but non of those give specific instructions. What I do know from finance is that the top line is a high and the one below is a low. The _high_ would be equivalent to the "upper shadow" and the _low_ to the "lower shadow" and these are the terms referred to in business. In terms of javascript I don't really what to look for. Thanks for your quick response!!

Comment: It's possible that there isn't a way to change it, the API definitely doesn't seem to mention anything.